# Authorize attribute on EntitySetController's GetEntityByKey not getting invoked

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, odata

**NB:** It should be noted that, after this question was answered, it appears that this specific question is very much related to OData and not to general C#.

I have a strange problem. I have derived from the `AuthorizeAttribute` class an `ApiAuthorize` attribute. This attribute does some additional ACL-like checking aside from the standard login procedure.

When I apply this attribute to an entire class, it works like expected on all methods. However, when I apply it separately on the methods, it does not work on all methods.

Following is a piece of code, using OData and Web Api:

```cs
public class UsersController : EntitySetController<User, int>
{
    [ApiAuthorize]
    public override IQueryable<User> Get()
    {
        DoSomething();
    }

    [ApiAuthorize]
    protected override User GetEntityByKey(int key)
    {
        DoSomethingElse();
    }
}
```

When I call the `Get` method using `/odata/Users`, the `OnAuthorization` method of the `ApiAuthorize` class is properly called. When I call the `GetEntityByKey` method using `/odata/Users(1284)` the `ApiAuthorize` attribute is completely ignored and the program jumps immediately inside the method. But, as I said earlier, when I remove the attributes from the methods and apply it to the class as a whole, the `GetEntityByKey` does indeed call the `ApiAuthorize` attribute.

By itself this is ofcourse strange, but even more so because before my transition to OData (thus using an `ApiController` instead of the currently used `EntitySetController`) this attribute was always working, no matter what way it was applied. So it seems like the `EntitySetController` breaks this.

Could it be that OData somehow breaks this implementation?

### Update

In order to answer the question of Josh E:

The derived attribute is quite large, so I'm guessing that the thumbed down version of it would not contribute to the question because it is trivial, but it looks like this:

```cs
public class ApiAuthorize : AuthorizeAttribute
{
    public override void OnAuthorization(System.Web.Http.Controllers.HttpActionContext actionContext)
    {
        HttpRequestHeaders headers = actionContext.Request.Headers;
        NameValueCollection getParams = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(actionContext.Request.RequestUri.Query);

        DoALotOfThings();
    }
}
```

This is only a very fragment of the derived attribute, but the code should at least arrive inside the `OnAuthorization` method. It should be noted that this method is the only method from the base class that I actually override, the rest is just inherited.

Comment: Can you post code from your derived attribute?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The behavior your are currently noticing with `GetEntityByKey` is expected. You would need to instead override the method `Get([FromODataUri] TKey key)` and apply the attribute to it, in which case you would see the behavior that you are expecting.

Following is the source code from `EntitySetController`. If you notice, GetEntityByKey is called from within the Get([FromODataUri] TKey key) action:

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Handles GET requests that attempt to retrieve an individual entity by key from the entity set.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="key">The entity key of the entity to retrieve.</param>
    /// <returns>The response message to send back to the client.</returns>
    public virtual HttpResponseMessage Get([FromODataUri] TKey key)
    {
        TEntity entity = GetEntityByKey(key);
        return EntitySetControllerHelpers.GetByKeyResponse(Request, entity);
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for your solution, this is indeed working. I used the tutorials of Mike Wasson as a basis, and in those he always uses the `Entity` returning methods of CRUD operations. I was not aware that these are insensitive to attributes, and that you should use the `HttpResponseMessage` returning methods instead. Maybe this could be added to these tutorials; I'm sure other developers would appreciate this.

Comment: @Kazu: Sure...also, I have updated the question title so that it reflects correctly about the problem here.